# Heroku app Application error

Tags: node.js, git, heroku

I have followed the steps that was on heroku's webpage

```
$ heroku login
$ cd my-project/
$ git init
$ heroku git:remote -a herokutestahmet
$ git add .
$ git commit -am "make it better"
$ git push heroku master
```

I have done all these,

it returned

```
 Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/mytest.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

but when I go to mytest.herokuapp.com  it says

```
Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

And also when I go to

https://git.heroku.com/mytest.git it says

```
Method not allowed
```

How do I host my app, it's a nodeJS app with express. please help.

***Edit***

In my local machine, I start the app by calling `node main` maybe i should do the same with the herokuapp, but how? maybe that is the error?

Comment: You can tell Heroku what command to start with by declaring a procfile (see, https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile). If you want to start with `node main`, your procfile would have the single line: `web: node main`. Commonly, for a Heroku ExpressJS app, you would have an index.js to start with, which you could call in the procfile with `web: node index.js`.

Comment: It also might help if you posted the logs in the question. You can see your logs by typing the command `heroku logs --tail` (--tail will keep the logs running).

Comment: my application crashes with these logs @illiteratecoder.Please help============logs========================== at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=chat-catt.herokuapp.com request_id=3854d7ae-2191-4ae1-970d-b53891d39f5f fwd="41.90.48.180" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https